# Can I upgrade an EC2 instance running Windows 2008 SP2 to Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008

I have an instance in Amazon EC2 running Windows 2008 SP2. Can I upgrade it to Windows 2008 R2, or would the EC2 architecture prevent me from upgrading?

Comment: Moved question to serverfault.
http://serverfault.com/questions/472307/can-an-ec2-instance-running-windows-2008-sp2-be-upgraded-to-windows-2008-r2

Comment: Serverfault question has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a 100% tested answer, but I do see several official responses from Amazon non this question. Their answers are a mixed. On Apr 2011: "no", Nov 2012: "yes".

Forum Thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=235938&#235938

1. Definitely would work: spinning up a wholly new server with the new OS version and then migrate everything.
2. Said to work: grab the Windows media and run the install - [Nov 8, 2012 comment from JonathanS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=235938&#398613).

The media is in Snapshots (search for All Amazon Snapshots or check out [Amazon's list](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1802?_encoding=UTF8&queryArg=searchQuery&fromSearch=1&searchPath=all&searchQuery=media%20snapshots)) and you can mount it as a volume from there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to mount a installation media volume (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=235938&#398613), but got an error during the installation. Windows cannot find the drivers for "RHEL SCSI Bus Miniport", which I suspect is a storage visualization driver used by the EC2 images.

Comment: By the way, I ended up installing a clean Windows Server R2 box from scratch, a lot of work.

Comment: @JanH Wow thanks for the tip. I did a server switch last night and wanted to move from Win2k8 to R2.. ran out of time and didn't. Sad to hear that I couldn't have just done the upgrade.
When in the process did you get that error?